# Place a scrollable div between two vertical divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have to design a responsive UI as below:

[image]

Header and footer are fixed at top and bottom. 
While a vertically scrollable list in between. 
If i didn't give a fixed height and list become overflow, list goes behind the footer. 
Also i need a button just above the footer with a fixed margin above this. I know this is a common scenario but i tried most but fails to my need.

Here is my code:

Html code:

```
<div id="top">top</div>
<div id="bottom">bottom</div>
<div id="mid">mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br></div>
```

CSS code:

```
#top
{
  border: solid 1px green;
}

#mid
{
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  border: solid 1px red;
  position: fixed;
  height: 89%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: none;
}

#bottom
{
  border: solid 1px blue;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

**Can anyone help me to build a responsive UI without giving a fixed height for each items.**

Comment: Post the code you have so far and I'll give you an answer

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: see the ionic example https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#lists

Comment: I have added my code @LGSon

Comment: @IjasAhamed Added an answer with 2 (based on browser support needed) versions, where both adjust the top and bottom height dynamically to their content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using Flexbox you can have dynamic height on both `top` and `bottom`

Set `display: flex` on the `wrapper`, give it a height and then set `flex-grow: 1` on the `middle`.

For the `button` I used absolute positioning.

*I also changed your `id`'s to classes, which is the recommend way to assign CSS rules*

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 60%;
}
.middle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
.top {
 background: lightgreen;
}
.bottom {
 position: relative;
 background: lightblue;
}
.button {
 position: absolute;
 top: -70px;
 right: 50px;
 background: lightgray;
 border-radius: 50%;
 padding: 20px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top">top</div>
  <div class="middle">
    Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br>    Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br> Long content<br>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
  bottom
    <div class="button">button</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you have to support older browsers, here is a version using CSS Table

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qmd039e4/)

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
}
.wrapper > div {
  display: table-row;
}
.top > div {
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 10px;
}
.middle {
  height: 100%;
}
.middle > div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.middle > div > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}
.bottom > div {
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}
.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: -70px;
  right: 50px;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 20px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top">
    <div>
      top
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div>
      <div>
        Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
        <br> Long content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div>
      bottom
      <div class="button">button</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is to keep `#top` and `#bottom` `position: fixed` and the let the `#mid` be `position: static OR relative`. The `#mid` should have a `padding: 50px 0` which prevents any overlapping.

Try this:

```css
#top {
  background: lightgreen;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  z-index: 1
}

#mid {
  padding: 50px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: none;
}

#bottom {
  background: lightblue;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  z-index: 1
}

#button {
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
  left: auto;
  right: 40px;
  z-index: 5
}
```

```html
<div id="top">top</div>
<div id="bottom">bottom
  <div id="button"><button>Click me!</button></div>
</div>

<div id="mid">mid - first<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid
  - last</div>
```

Comment: Add a button above footer

Answer (score 1):

A sample

```css
/* Table structure with ul and li (responsive) */

 html {
   height: 100%;
 }
 
 html body {
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
 }
 
 html body .container-fluid.body-content {
   width: 100%;
   overflow-y: auto;
 }
 
 header {
   background-color: #42d1f4;
   min-height: 50px;
   width: 100%;
 }
 
 footer {
   background-color: #7af441;
   min-height: 30px;
   width: 100%;
 }
 
 .headingsmall {
   color: #3a4355;
   font-weight: bold;
   -webkit-text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #119af2;
   -moz-text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #119af2;
   -o-text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #119af2;
   font: 400 24px/1.4 'Cutive', Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
   text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #119af2;
   text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 
 .servicetable {
   border: 1px solid #000;
   list-style: none;
   padding: 2px;
   width: 49%;
   display: inline-block;
 }
 
 .kc_fab_main_btn {
   background-color: #F44336;
   float: right;
   width: 60px;
   height: 60px;
   border-radius: 100%;
   background: #F44336;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   color: #FFF;
   font-size: 36px;
   box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
   transition: .3s;
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 }
 
 .kc_fab_main_btn:focus {
   transform: scale(1.1);
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <h3>Header</h3>
</header>
<div class="container-fluid body-content">
  <ul>
<li class="servicetable"><img src="http://i529.photobucket.com/albums/dd333/sahilpoply/61.png" width="16px" border="0" alt="Sahil popli" /> front desk</li>
<li class="servicetable"><img src="http://i529.photobucket.com/albums/dd333/sahilpoply/210.png" width="16px" border="0" alt="Sahil popli" /> 24/7 International channels</li>
<li class="servicetable"><img src="http://i529.photobucket.com/albums/dd333/sahilpoply/201.png" width="16px" border="0" alt="Sahil popli" /> Shuttle service from/to the airport*</li>
<li class="servicetable"><img src="http://i529.photobucket.com/albums/dd333/sahilpoply/94.png" width="16px" border="0" alt="Sahil popli" /> Smoking/non-smoking rooms</li>
<li class="servicetable"><img src="http://i529.photobucket.com/albums/dd333/sahilpoply/50.png" width="16px" border="0" alt="Sahil popli" /> Doctor On Call</li>
<li class="servicetable"><img src="http://i529.photobucket.com/albums/dd333/sahilpoply/61.png" width="16px" border="0" alt="Sahil popli" /> front desk</li>
<li class="servicetable"><img src="http://i529.photobucket.com/albums/dd333/sahilpoply/210.png" width="16px" border="0" alt="Sahil popli" /> 24/7 International channels</li>
<li class="servicetable"><img src="http://i529.photobucket.com/albums/dd333/sahilpoply/201.png" width="16px" border="0" alt="Sahil popli" /> Shuttle service from/to the airport*</li>
<li class="servicetable"><img src="http://i529.photobucket.com/albums/dd333/sahilpoply/94.png" width="16px" border="0" alt="Sahil popli" /> Smoking/non-smoking rooms</li>
<li class="servicetable"><img src="http://i529.photobucket.com/albums/dd333/sahilpoply/50.png" width="16px" border="0" alt="Sahil popli" /> Doctor On Call</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<footer>
  <button class="kc_fab_main_btn">+</button>
  <h3>Footer</h3>
</footer>
```

Comment: Please add button above the footer

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main {
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
.body {
    margin-top: 25px;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"><h1 align="center">Header</h1></div>
<div class="body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamcorper, pellentesque consequatur, euismod praesentium nulla. Maecenas sed, vestibulum orci. Turpis sapien sed ac et urna sit, eget lectus proin, class id magna penatibus turpis et nec, ante consectetuer a amet porta a eu, rutrum a mollis aliquam congue. Dictum neque. A magna velit, morbi proin ligula aliquam donec neque.
Lorem eget. Montes praesent auctor nec integer vel wisi, integer ut risus, ac dolor nullam et dolor vel. Turpis praesent, debitis sed amet potenti nec dolor suspendisse, dui feugiat condimentum mi neque at viverra, consectetuer elit ante praesent nulla wisi curabitur, accumsan nec eum suscipit sed sed scelerisque. Rhoncus non placerat dui. Laoreet ut elit hymenaeos amet ipsum, lobortis convallis accumsan. Tristique dolor viverra ipsum rhoncus dui, elit cras penatibus donec per wisi, at praesent nullam, elit lectus per est aliquam, class placerat lectus taciti adipiscing. Vivamus nulla tellus, velit nullam duis, pulvinar accumsan ullamcorper magna sodales sed. Pulvinar lectus adipiscing. Nec lectus, lectus vehicula integer facilisi, dignissim diam augue arcu laborum non consectetuer, est et urna ante consequat. Turpis eu. Tempor nec enim arcu amet molestie auctor, aliquam cum.</div>
<div class="main"><h1 align="center">Footer</h1></div>
```

Comment: Need a button above footer

Answer (score 0):

```css
#top
{
  //float: top;
  border: solid 1px green;
  width: 100%;
  background: #8BC34A;
  /*position: fixed;
  top: 0;*/
}

#mid
{
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  border: solid 1px red;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: none;
  color:blue;
}

#bottom
{
  border: solid 1px blue;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
  background: #8BC34A;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">top</div>
<div id="bottom">bottom</div>
<div id="mid">mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br>mid<br></div>
```

Comment: Misses some fields behind bottom footer.

Comment: you have visible middle part over footer @IjasAhamed

Comment: a "mid" item is behind the "bottom". It can't go behind that.

Comment: Now mid is above bottom.

Comment: so what you want its ok or not